# how to maintain viewstate for jqxGrid in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, viewstate, jqxgrid

i am using jqxGrid in jqWidgets library. problem is that when doing an event on the page that posts back to the server, the grid will be empty which is logical because it is bound in js not like the traditional asp.net gridview. so jqxGrid seems to be amazing gridview but unfoertunately it is useless if it cannot do basic maintenance of its state. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [saveloadstate.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/saveloadstate.htm?classic). I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ok, but via the getstate method, you can get the Grid's state. It is a JSON object. You can store it on your server and load it via the loadstate method of jqxGrid.